# python to_bytes() to return an even number of digits

Tags: python, hex, byte

I'm trying to convert an int (i.e. 3490) into 2 bytes via the `to_bytes()` function and instead of returning **b'\x0d\xa2'**, I'm getting **b'\r\xa2'**. What am I missing here and how can I get the former to return?

Comment: `\r` and `\x0d` are the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that but is there a way that I can get the former for display purposes.

Comment: So, what do you mean by 'return' in 'how can I get the former to return'? In my limited experience, `b'\r\xa2'` has always been displayed as such.

Comment: If you print a bytes object, various individual byte values will be represented by well-known escape sequences. For example 2314 becomes b'\t\n'. If you need a different representation then you'll need to write some code to do that

Answer (score 0):

The two expressions are equivalent, as `ord('\r') == 0x0d`. In other words, `b'\x0d\xa2' == b'\r\xa2'`.

If you're looking for how to get a even-sized hex string for bytes, you may try

```py
>>> 3490 .to_bytes(2).hex()
'0da2'
```

Comment: I've looked into that but the type is 'str' and would want the type to still be 'byte' if possible.

Answer (score 0):

When You Print the value python represents it in a string thus in ASCII, \x0d (which represents the byte with hexadecimal value 0x0d) is represented as \r, because in ASCII encoding, the byte 0x0d corresponds to the carriage return character (i.e. '\r').

If You Want to See the Hex representation just call .hex():

```
num = 3490
result_bytes = num.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')
print(result_bytes.hex())
```